# Finding a specific symbol and the digits in front of it using Reg Ex

Tags: regex

I would like to find an expression in a string in following form:

```
{digits}!
```

That is, it should recognize an expression where a digit sequenced is closed by `!`.

I know that I could use the `*` in Reg Ex, but that would take everything (all symbols). Is there anyway this can be solved using Reg Ex?

EDIT: I am trying to replace factorial notation: i.e. 4! 3! with 4!0 (emulating a classic operator).

Comment: Can you please given an example?

Comment: Something as simple as `\d+!` would work??

Comment: Do you need to catch the curly braces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this regex:

```
[0-9]+\!
```

see [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gK5xT0)

Comment: Please add some additional content to your answer by explaining how this regex statement works.

Comment: +1 for a great answer and since you were first to answer, I mark this as an answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very specific

Assumed you need to find out `999!` in the string `abcd999!xyz`.

Try match this regex against your string,

```
var regex = /\d+!/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
\{[0-9]+\}!
```

It matches a literal `{` followed by one or more digits plus a close curly brace `}` and atlast it must have `!`.

[See demo](http://regex101.com/r/wO7dV2)

Comment: This answer is currently considered a low quality post. Please could you add some detail explaining the different parts of the Regex to improve the quality of the answer.

Comment: Note that the flagging system for that isn't perfect; if it's correct then it's correct. Being succinct isn't always bad.

Answer (score 1):

Most RegEx Engines support the `\d` class for decimal digits. Thus you might try

```
\d+!
```

. Alternatively, try

```
[0-9]+!
```